# FormValidator y Sweet Alert

Tags: jquery, ajax, sweetalert

Tengo el siguiente problema.
Necesito validar unos campos, que de hecho lo estoy haciendo con formValidator y funciona.
Una vez que los campos son validados, envio los datos por post y ajax y muestro el popup de sweet alert preguntando si quiero o no enviar el formulario.
El problema es que cuando presion el boton submit del form sin haber llenado los campos requerido, el alert igual se muestra cuando este deberia aparecer luego del success de ajax.

```
$('#envia_pedidoE').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    excluded: ':disabled',

    fields: {
        obs: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Ingrese Obs. de Pedido.'
                }
            }
        },
        date: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Seleccione Fecha'
                },
                date: {
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    message: 'Formato Fecha NO VALIDO'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

esos son input que valido (y valida ok).

```
$('#envia_pedidoE').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var datos = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "envioE.php",
        data : datos,

        success:function(data){
        var href = "real_pedidos.php";
            swal({
                title: "Realizará Envío de Pedido",
                text: "Para <?php echo $laboratorio;?>", 
                icon: "info",
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true,
            })
            .then((envio) => {
              if (envio) {
                swal("Su Pedidos Fue Enviado Correctamente", {
                  icon: "success",
                });
                window.location.href = href;
              } else {
                swal("Ha Cancelado el Envío del Pedido");
              }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

y ese es el ajax con el success que es en donde deberia mostrar el alert preguntando si quiero enviar el formulario.

Alguna idea? desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo deseas preguntar antes de realizar la petición si desea realizar el pedido, si esto es así debes lanzar primero el swal confirm y dependiendo de la acción tomada realizar o no la petición

```js
$('#envia_pedidoE').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var datos = $(this).serialize();                             
  swal({
    title: "Realizará Envío de Pedido",
    text: "Para <?php echo $laboratorio;?>", 
    icon: "info",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
  })
  .then((envio) => {
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "envioE.php",
      data : datos,
      success:function(data){
        var href = "real_pedidos.php";
        swal("Su Pedidos Fue Enviado Correctamente", {
          icon: "success",
        });
        window.location.href = href;
      }
    })  
  })
  .catch(reject=>{
    swal("Ha Cancelado el Envío del Pedido");
  });
});
```