# Preguntar antes de enviar en peticion post

Tags: javascript

como puedo preguntar antes de enviar ?

Quiero enviar un formulario, pero antes quiero preguntar si esta seguro, quiero hacerlo con la libreria sweet, o solo funciona para peticiones ajax?

```js
$('.enviarClick').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this).parents('form');
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
  }, function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) form.submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<form action="/evaluacion/crearEvaluacion" method="post" onsubmit="return validarSiNumero();" id='enviarClick'></form>
```

Comment: Hola, tal vez encuentres la respuesta en otra pregunta que han formulado antes [FormValidator y Sweet Alert
](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155901/formvalidator-y-sweet-alert), saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@hubman respondiendo a tu pregunta: **Como puedo preguntar antes de enviar ?**

La cancelación del envío de un formulario se puede realizar de varias formas todo depende de que camino quieras usar.

- Prevenir la ejecución del formulario capturando el click del input/boton con tipo submit y usando preventDefault.

```js
function enviar() {
  alert('enviado');
}

function preguntar(event) {
  var opcion = confirm("Desea enviar el formulario");
  if(!opcion) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript: enviar()">
  <button type="submit" onclick="preguntar(event)">
    Enviar
  </button>
</form>
```

**Nota**: este método tiene fallas ya que no captura otros eventos como el `keyDown` si el usuario presiona la tecla `Enter`.

- Eliminar el atributo action del formulario para evitar envios accidentales

```js
function enviar(){
 var opcion = confirm('Desea enviar el formulario ?');

  if(opcion) {
    alert('Enviado');
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
 <button onclick="enviar()">
   Enviar
 </button>
</form>
```

**Nota** aunque esta solución llega a ser mas elegante, se necesitan más conocimientos para poder enviar el formulario. Ya sea por AJAX capturando los valores del formulario o incluyendo el atributo `action` por javascript y lanzando el `envento submit` posteriormente.

Volviendo a tu ejemplo sería la opción de ejecutarlo en el `onclick` y hacer la validación en el`onsubmit`y de hecho está correcto hacerlo ahí. Lo que falla no es la lógica de preguntar  o validar si no el uso de la librería sweet.

```js
function esNumero(value) {
  return value / value === 1;
}

function validar(event, form) {
  var inputs = $(form).serializeArray();
  var numero = inputs.find(input => input.name === 'numero' );
  return esNumero(numero.value); // && otras validaciones;
}

function preguntar(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: {
      cancel: {
        text: "Cancel",
        value: null,
        visible: true,
        className: "",
        closeModal: true,
      },
      confirm: {
        text: "Yes, delete it!",
        value: true,
        visible: true,
        className: "",
        closeModal: true
      }
    }
  }).then(function(value) {
     var form = $('#miFormulario');
    if (value) form.submit();
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<form action="javascript: alert('Enviado')" method="post" onsubmit="validar(event, this)" id="miFormulario">
  <label>Numero</label>
  <input type="text" name="numero" />
  <!-- type como button y no como submit -->
  <input type="button" onclick="preguntar(event)" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Había varios errores, ya que habian cambiado la API con la últimas versiones.

Esto pasa porque usas el link de la CDN hacia la última versión y no una versión específica.